# Use one variable in multiple chained LINQ queries

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, lambda

Is this fair to use a single lambda expression variable in multiple chained calls? For example:

```
MyList.Where(i => i.ID > 20).OrderBy(i => i.Name);
```

So does `i` used in `Where()` remain independent of the `i` used in `OrderBy()` or can they have some hidden side-effects on each other, so that I must used different variable for each? Also, does your answer hold for VB.NET too?

I'm asking this because I have read in a slightly different context that I should not use foreach variable in LINQ queries directly and instead make a local copy of the variable inside the loop. Is there some similar effect hidden in the above code too?

Comment: You can do it, but whether or not it'll be confusing and hard to manage is a different question. The point about `foreach` variables is probably concerning closures.

Comment: This may have details [How does it work in C#?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383749/How-does-it-work-in-Csharp-Part-Csharp-LINQ-in-d#paraIdWhereSelect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambda expressions are basically a shorter way of writing anonymous methods.  Therefore, the `i` in your lambda examples is the same thing as a parameter in an anonymous method.  In other words, they are independent of one another, just as parameters of different methods are independent of one another.

For the sake of readability, it may be worthwhile to change `i` to `person`, or something similar.  E.g. `MyList.Where(person => person.ID > 20).OrderBy(person => person.Name);`

Regarding `foreach`: Read about closures in this context on Eric Lippert's blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Excerpt:

> Because ()=>v means "return the current value of variable v", not "return the value v was back when the delegate was created". Closures close over variables, not over values. And when the methods run, clearly the last value that was assigned to v was 120, so it still has that value.

Comment: I like this one more.

Answer (score 6):

They are  completely independent. Actually, each time you declare a lambda you declare also range variables, which are local to this labda expression. So the `i` in the `Where(i => i.ID > 20)` is completely different from the `i` in `OrderBy(i => i.Name)`. In the first case `i` refers to the random element of `MyList`, and then `i` refers to the random element of the sequence that comes from the `Where` clause, which would be the sequence of all the elements of `MyList` that have an `ID>20`.

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate a bit more, this is fine:

```
MyList.Where(i => i.ID > 20).OrderBy(i => i.Name);
```

Those two variables called `i` are completely separate and only exist within the context of their respective lambda expressions. However, this is not:

```
int i = 0;
MyList.Where(i => i.ID > 20).OrderBy(i => i.Name);
```

Now those `i`'s in your lambdas conflict with the `i` defined in the parent scope.

The issue with `foreach` is a little more subtle and slightly tangential to your original question. If you have this:

```
foreach (var foo in fooList) 
{
    var filteredList = MyList.Where(i => i.ID > foo.Id).OrderBy(i => i.Name);
}
```

The problem here is because LINQ uses *deferred* execution and references the loop variable `foo` so it will create a closure to include `foo`. The problem is, it doesn't *copy* `foo` it actually has a reference to the variable. So when you finally execute your lambda's by iterating it, or:

```
var bar = filteredList.ToList();
```

The value of `foo` in your `Where` lambda will be the value of `foo` *right now*, not the value when the lambda was declared. So `foo` will always be the last item from `fooList`. Copying the variable fixes this problem because now it will close over that distinct variable (that only exists for that one iteration of the loop) rather than the loop variable.

```
foreach (var foo in fooList) 
{
    var copy = foo;
    var filteredList = MyList.Where(i => i.ID > copy.Id).OrderBy(i => i.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See: [Variable Scope in Lambda Expression - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

> Variables introduced within a lambda expression are not visible in the
>   outer method.

So in your case your `Where` clause, you declared `i` which is only visible inside the `Where` clause and thus independent of the one declared in `OrderBy` clause.